# $() is not a function on calling modal dialog google map resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have the error below `Uncaught type error, $() is not a function` , highlight `$("#mapModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {.........`
What should I do?

```
$("#mapModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

I have added below:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mapps/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/mapps/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/mapps/assets/js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Client side web error]

Quote: I have reverse the order of jquery and jquery tools, it is working to show google map. On the other hand, it has below new javascript errors.

[image: Two new errors]

[image: new error 1 about .tabs]

[image: new error 2 about fadeIn]

Comment: You should add them *above*, not below your code

Answer (score 1):

First you should include all your library files then the code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mapps/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/mapps/assets/js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/mapps/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Ordering of the library files 'also matters.

Then add the code

```
$("#mapModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

Please use `jQuery.min.js` instead of `jQuery slim version`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jqu‌​ery.min.js"></script‌​>`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: sorry I have followed but still failed and error also the same.

Comment: @AMMA Please provide more info. Post your code in `jsfiddle` with similar scenario.

Comment: @AMMA I can see your jQuery library is not loading or may be loading after boortstrap library. Check the jQuery library in browser network panel.

Comment: Hi, it is working now. It can show the map. I have reverse the order of jquery and jquery tools. On the other hand it has another javascript error as attached.

Comment: Hi, I have updated this post with new errors. I guess it may need to add jquery ui. If yes, should i place before jquery tools or between jquery tools and jquery?? what version should i use??

Comment: @AMMA `jQuery UI` needs to be place after `jQuery`. I would suggest you to use `jQuery.min.js` instead of slim version of `jQuery`.

Comment: I have added this line after jquery. still same error. Anything I am missing??

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @AMMA Please use `jQuery.min.js` instead of `jQuery slim`. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks, it has no errors now. I am using this https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Comment: @AMMA Welcome buddy :) Please accept the answer. Will update the answer as well.